# Jquery Validate Plugin is applying rules only including jquery.validate.min file

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, plugins

I am getting the validation errors in all my forms and I have not even applied the `$('form').validate()` method to any form.

I understand that after the document is loaded, I have to apply the `validate()` method on the form that I want to apply the validation functionality, but in this case, I am only including the plugin files, and the validations are been applied on all my forms.

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Regards! (And sorry about my english)

Comment: Can we see the html and js code you have

Comment: I have no any js code. I am only including the 'jquery.validate.min.js' file

Answer (score 0):

Please be more details about the issue....
Which version you are using and provide dummy code will better for understanding.

Have a look on the below point may be help you:
You must have added attributes to the form inputs like "required",'numbers'...etc

Comment: The version of the jQuery Validation Plugin that I am using is is v1.15.0. And yes, I have added the 'required' attribute on some fields in several forms. But I don't have any js code to apply the plugin, I am only including the 'jquery.validation.min.js' in the <head> section.